# Django development server stops after logging into admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have installed django 3.0 in python 3.7 and started a basic django project. I have created a superuser and run the development server using `python manage.py runserver`. When I go to `localhost:8000/admin` it shows me ui to login after I entered my credentials it redirects back to `localhost:8000/admin` but at that time server stops running without any error on console.

The last message I see in log file is

```
(0.002) SELECT "django_session"."session_key", "django_session"."session_data", "django_session"."expire_date" FROM "django_session" WHERE ("django_session"."expire_date" > '2019-12-11T08:52:16.929697+00:00'::timestamptz AND "django_session"."session_key" = 'tqpcf2gv6iqatc42pdmz6zdjpy7iri37') LIMIT 21; args=(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 11, 8, 52, 16, 929697, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'tqpcf2gv6iqatc42pdmz6zdjpy7iri37')
(0.002) SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1 LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
```

Has someone faced this issue? What could be the solution?

**EDIT:** I found someone faced same issue in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/e5m7zv/accessing_admin_is_crashing_the_server/) looks like this is a bug in django

Uninstalling django then installing django 2.2.8 with `pip install "django>=2.2,<3"` helped.

Comment: Do you see any error on console?

Comment: You have a backslash instead of a slash in the URL.

Comment: no error in console, it just stops

Comment: What do you mean "stops running" ? Does the process exits, or is it still there but not doing anything ? In this last case, what happens if you try and refresh the page ?

Comment: ya the process exists and browser shows 'connection refused' error. If i restart the server same thing happens again as soon as I go the '/admin' unless I clear the cookies, after which it shows the login page

Answer (score 1):

Check up your python version. It should be 3.8+ for Django 3.0. I had the same problem when I was using python 3.7.

Comment: `Django 3.0 supports Python 3.6, 3.7, and 3.8` : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/3.0/

Answer (score 1):

Either try upgrading to python 3.8 or downgrade to Django 2.2. Upgrading to Python 3.8 worked for me. Also, don't forget to add Python 3.8's path and pip's Path to your System's Environment variable, otherwise, it'll keep using pip 3.7's path.

Answer (score 0):

Django version 3.0.1 not helped.
but I find a way to access the admin site without crashing the server.
login to the main page or your apps main page in the admin site stops the server.
but you can log in to URLs like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/YourAppsName/YourModelsName/

but still going to apps main page crashes the server.