# Python failed when trying to log into admin page of Django

Tags: python, django

I set up Django in Pycharm and try to log into the admin page,however,the page failed.
I was able to open the page where I am supposed to enter the username and password,but when I
click the 'enter'button it just crash and showing that Python has failed.It really makes me confused... The picture shows the situation.
[image]

### Finally I uninstall Django3 and install 2.2.8 which solved--it seems like a bug

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Sure I did...It says "No migrations to apply".

Comment: if you are using django 3.0 then some users are facing this issue, check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59281990/django-development-server-stops-after-logging-into-admin

Answer (score -1):

It seems that, there is an issue with run time execution. Also, try once more time after restarting the system.

Comment: I have already try to restart...It does not work...For views.py,as I am just doing a test,it is really simple,just like below,`def index(request):
    article=models.Article.objects.get(pk=1)
    return render(request, 'blog/index.html',{'article':article})`

Comment: @Guatam Please write your comments/suggestions as comments to question if you can instead not as answers.